# jQuery Validation plug-in that works with dynamic controls

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

I've tried the plug-in found [here](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/), but I can't get it to work with dynamic controls.

What are some other validators that will work with dynamic controls?

Dynamic Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wY6xt/2/

Comment: what exactly doesn't work?  let's see some of your existing code?   that plugin is the best out there (from what i've seen).  you just need to get it set up right!

Comment: Example: http://jsfiddle.net/wY6xt/2/

Comment: Your dynamically generated inputs have same name - it's a problem, since error message appears in the label for input with that name. Also td after dynamic inputs is not closed. You need dynamically generated different names for each input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do 'inspect element' in FF you see that all new inputs do have 'error' class added if empty, but since all inputs have the same name, error message only shows once. If you call dynamic field something else it will show twice (once for static input, once for first dynamic one. Now if you have all inputs named differently (and you need that anyway) it'll work fine.

Comment: That's it!  I had noticed that but didn't know why it was doing it. Anyway, I updated the example to show it working with unique ids: http://jsfiddle.net/wY6xt/3/

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple ways you can accomplish this.

- When adding the inputs dynamically, use the [**.rules()**](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules) method to add the appropriate validation rules.
- Add classes to the inputs, e.g. `<input type="text" ... class="required email">`

Answer (score 0):

haven't you tried the [dynamic demo](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/dynamic-totals.html) ? It works very well... What are your requirements ?

Comment: Ok, I didn't see that example. I'm just using classes. Does that mean the `addMethod` has to be used for dynamic forms?

Comment: the `addMethod` function is just here to add a custom validation rule. The dynamic part of the validation lies in the `$("#orderform").delegate` callback, especially with the `valid()` call